# Post a message in MS Teams channel with bot (delegated permissions)

Tags: microsoft-teams, graph-explorer

I want to create a bot in MS Teams that posts a message in a MS Teams channel any time a new ticket is created in ServiceNow.
For the integration I am using Zapier and, to do so, I use the API call `POST {Service URL of your bot}/v3/conversations` in [MS documentation] ([https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/bot-v3/bot-conversations/bots-conv-proactive?tabs=http#creating-a-channel-conversation:~:text=Examples%20for%20creating%20a%20channel%20conversation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/bot-v3/bot-conversations/bots-conv-proactive?tabs=http#creating-a-channel-conversation:%7E:text=Examples%20for%20creating%20a%20channel%20conversation)).

[image: bot setup]
I created the bot in Azure but here is where I got stuck. Could you please help me to find the `Service URL of the bot` and to set up the `delegated authentication` needed for the bot to work?

[image: Bot page]

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Azure portal and sign in with your Azure account.
In the left pane, select Resource groups and choose the resource group where your bot is deployed.
Select the Web App Bot resource from the list of resources in the group.
In the Overview section, you will find the Messaging Endpoint. Copy this URL as it is the Service URL of your bot.
Now, to set up delegated authentication for your bot, you can follow the steps mentioned in the documentation:
[Configure SSO for your bot in Azure AD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/authentication/bot-sso-register-aad?tabs=windows)

Comment: Hi, I followed your instructions but on the Bot's page the Messaging Endpoint field is empty (I added a picture in my question)

Comment: Please go the configuration section of your bot and update messaging endpoint properly.